# how can I choose the fields to retrieve with FT.AGGREGATE?

Tags: redis, redisearch

I need to sort the documents by the field `type` equals `folder` and I only need the `id` to be retrieved, however, I can't seem to make only the `id` to be returned.

`FT.AGGREGATE Query:DirectoryItem * APPLY "@type == 'folder'" as isFolder LIMIT 0 50 SORTBY 2 @isFolder DESC APPLY @id as id`

The above query returns the `type`, `isFolder` and `id` fields.

Can I only retrieve `id` somehow?

Comment: Currently, you cannot. Are you trying to optimize the network traffic?

Comment: not only that but my calls are dynamic, so would be much easier to retrieve only the ID. If not I will have to make the generic method count the APPLY to know where the id field is

Comment: Support for the RETURN clause as in FT.Search would solve this.

Comment: @PieterCailliau created an issue there: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/2591